# Excel error - The component is not in a valid state. The external columns are out of synchronization

Tags: excel, ssis, synchronization, metadata

I've got an SSIS package which reads an Excel file. I'm using a SQL command to read the data.

```
SELECT * FROM [CMPanel$A4:CR]
```

This was working fine.

The excel spreadsheet is updated with new data added to the bottom. So I grabbed the latest file, backed up my current one and put the latest one in place.

Now when I click the Data Flow for the Excel Source I get the following;

> The component is not in a valid state. The validation errors are:
>   Warning at {8746F0E0-E404-4F5D-A52B-97BD52E63E43} [Read Application Profile Excel Source [1]]: The external columns for component "Read Application Profile Excel Source" (1) are out of synchronization with the data source columns. The external column "NoName12" (299) needs to be removed from the external columns.

The `NoName12` is my column `CR`. Nothing has changed with it. Data still exists in this column.

Why is it complaining about this column all of sudden?

So I opened the newer Excel file and go to the bottom and copy the 44 newer rows from this new excel file to the backup copy. I save this as my new file and the SSIS package is fine.

I won't be able to do this in production. All we will do is drop the newer .xls into the folder.

Why is SSIS thinking the metadata changed when it didn't?

Comment: It must have changed in a way that is not so easy to spot.  Analyze more closely and look for anything that SSIS might be seeing as a new column in the new file.   It might be the new column is taking the place of `CR` in the meta-data, which makes SSIS think that `CR` is a new column.